# Extract data from span tag inside div tag

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

My problem may be trivial because I am new to web scraping. Please see following HTML code:

```
<div class="price-container clearfix">
<span class="sale-flag-percent">-40%</span>  
<span class="price-box ri"> 
<span class="price "><span data-currency-iso="PKR">Rs.</span> 
<span dir="ltr" data-price="5999">&nbsp;5,999</span>  </span>  
<span class="price -old "><span data-currency-iso="PKR">Rs.</span> 
<span dir="ltr" data-price="9999">&nbsp;9,999</span>  </span> </span>
</div>
```

So far I am able to get access to outermost `div.price-container clearfix`. But I am not able to get inner spans and get the price of the product. Any way to gain access to inner span and get prices.

Comment: where is ur code?

Answer (score 1):

Given the html in your question it should be quite easy to select the span tags using [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).
An example,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="price-container clearfix">
<span class="sale-flag-percent">-40%</span>  
<span class="price-box ri"> 
<span class="price "><span data-currency-iso="PKR">Rs.</span> 
<span dir="ltr" data-price="5999">&nbsp;5,999</span>  </span>  
<span class="price -old "><span data-currency-iso="PKR">Rs.</span> 
<span dir="ltr" data-price="9999">&nbsp;9,999</span>  </span> </span>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.select('div.price-container.clearfix span[data-price]')
prices = [i.text.strip() for i in tags]

print(prices)
```

---

This expression:

```
div.price-container.clearfix span[data-price]
```

selects all 'span' tags that have a 'data-price' attribute, if they are descendants of a 'div' tag that has 'price-container' and 'clearfix' class attributes.

The result is a list with the text of both span tags. If you want a different selector for each tag, you could use the `span.price` and `span.price.-old` parent tags.

```
new_prices = soup.select('span[class="price "] span[data-price]')
old_prices = soup.select('span[class="price -old "] span[data-price]')
```

This will result in two lists of tags, one for each price category.

Comment: Yes it did work. Thanks a lot. Just one more thing. There are two prices, new price and old price. How can I get them separately like storing in two different variables, e.g., new_price and old_price.

Comment: If there are only two items and the old price is always the second item, then you can just unpack the list, eg `new_price, old_price = prices`.

Comment: The first solution of accessing new and old prices worked and it is also close to what I intended to do. However, the second solution of unpacking list gives Value Error too many values to unpack expected 2. In first solution, 'new_price = soup.select_one('span.price span[data-price]').text' works. Anyhow, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Very glad to help! About the `ValueError`, it seems like your list has more than two items. In that case you can use the last two selectors in my answer or arrange your list in pairs of two.